# Visual Studio - how to check which function is running

Tags: c#

I am trying to debug an application that runs on multiple threads.
At some point the application stops on one function and takes a long time to process it.
Is there any way to check at which point the application stops?
I am not able to give that many breakpoints.

Regards

Comment: Use a profiler?

Comment: As a poor-man's tool, just run it in a debugger and break the debugger when the application stops. Open the Threads and Call Stacks windows (Debug -> Windows). Double-click on each of your threads to see what they're doing. If they're stuck in Runtime code you can't see, double-click on lines in the Call Stacks window to see how the thread got there

Comment: @canton7 unfortunately no matter what thread I click on in the call stack I get the external code.

Comment: @monika-115 It's likely that most of your threads are just sitting around in the ThreadPool waiting for work. Keep clicking through them: you should find one or two which are actually executing your code

Comment: Does the code call external package like NuGet in this process if so you need to include symbols in your visual studio